# Where should I put my photos so that they are visible in Unity's photo lens?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses, photo

I have many pictures but for instance put in `~/Dropbox/Photos` and they are not detected by unity's photo lens.

I have even tried putting some of them in `~/Pictures` but still no Pictures in the lens.

Additionally is there any possibility to change the directory with the Photos that the lens would read the photos from ?

Answer (score 1):

Edit `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` to include:

```
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Pictures"
```

OR

```
XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Dropbox/Photos"
```

Or add in the `Pictures` folder, and run:

```
xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update
```

---

The photo scope may need some extra packages - so run:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:scopes-packagers/ppa && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity-lens-photo unity-scope-shotwell unity-scope-flick
```

Unity-lens-photo is also available [here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/webapps_preview/precise/main/base/unity-lens-photo), but it sounds like you have it installed anyway.

Comment: I have just tried it and still no photos in the lens. Even restarted `lightdm`.

Comment: This was mostly a guess, as I guessed it would search the setup pictures directory. Rebooting the entire computer might also help :-). Just found something as well.